# Count the number of dots[.] , ! and ? in a text

Tags: java, regex, string

Im working on java project and I need to count the number of dots,! and ? in a string. My current approach is to use regex. I used the following code but its not giving the correct result.

```
for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        String w = words[i];
        if(w.matches("(.)+[.!?]")){
            count++;    //increasing the count.
        }
    }
```

For some other function I have converted the string into array of words. So I'm using it in this.
I want to increase the count by one for each occurrence of dot,! or ? indicating a terminating point of a sentence. For example

> test. - count increases by 1
>   test.. - count increase by 1
>   test?. - count increases by 1

Repeated use of symbols shouldn't increase the count.
Can you tell me what is wrong in here?

Comment: What do you think `[(.)+[.!?]]` matches and why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I checked some tutorial on regex and that's what I came up with. (.)+[.!?] means (any number of characters)(one of .!?) isn't that so?
I made a mistake on the code posted and I edited it

Comment: Can some one tell me why is this down voted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wildcard in the regex.

```
    int count = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < words.length; i++ )
        if( words[i].matches(".*[.!?]") )
            count++;
```

.*[.!?] will match all strings that end in a period, exclamation point, or question mark.

The first `.` is unescaped, and stands for any character. The `*` means 0 or more of the previous thing.  So 0 or more of any character.  The `.` in the brackets is escaped, so it's just a regular period.

Comment: By dots I means dots at the end of a word indicating end of a sentence. For my work I'm going to need words like test... to be counted only once.

Comment: It throws an exception.

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*[.!?]

Comment: @isuru-buddhika Sorry, I forgot a period. Forgot this isn't a Linux command line...lol.  I tested it this time so I know it works.

Comment: Wouldn't it make much sense it I used (".+[.!?]") ?  Giving 1 or more of any character+one of . ! ?

Comment: @isuru-buddhika
That's fine.  I just didn't know if you required at least one letter or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70505/discussion-between-isuru-buddhika-and-kacy-raye).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is this one-liner:

```
int count = str.length() - str.replaceAll("[.!?]+", "").length()
```

Rather than count char matches, delete them and compare lengths.

Comment: it is not much, but no one thinks this answer spit on performance face? taking a simple task, and make it consume memory and time... dis-like.

Comment: this one is empty string safe, .match was throwing an error on me. ty

Answer (score 0):

You can do -

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String str = "Test, test!.\tTEST:\nTeST?;";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[.!?]");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
    int count = 0;
    while(matcher.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Count : " + count);

}
```

and the output is - `3` as expected.

> Can you tell me why the same regex in str.matches("[.!?]) is not giving the expected result?

Because `str.matches("[.!?])`  matches the whole String and not if regex is found in the String. Above regex will work if string is '.', '?', or '!' -

```
    String s = ".";
    System.out.println(s.matches("[.!?]"));
```

will give `true`.

Comment: Can you tell me why the same regex in str.matches("[.!?]) is not giving the expected result?

Comment: Because your String does not match regex `[.!?]`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't some of those words taken separately return true?

Comment: FYI - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29